# ReactJS - access to props child in render for props transfer

Tags: reactjs

When I try to access `{this.props}` in render, it crashes my page. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
var React = require('react');
var DefaultLayout = React.createFactory(require('../layouts/Default'));
var ReactGridLayout = React.createFactory(require('react-grid-layout'));

var DesktopStore = require("../stores/DesktopStore");
var _ = require('lodash');
// var classNames = require('classnames');

var HomePage = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'Index.jsx',

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            zoomed: DesktopStore.get('zoom'),
            layout: this.generateLayout()
        };
    },

    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            layout: DefaultLayout,
            grid: {
                items: 20,
                cols: 80,
                rowHeight: 30,
                verticalCompact: false,
                autoSize: false,
                isResizable: false,
                margin: [5,5]
            }
        };
    },

    generateGridDOM: function(){
        return _.map(_.range(this.props.grid.items), function(i) {
            return (<div key={i}><span className="text">{i}</span></div>);
        });
    },

    generateLayout: function(){
        var p = this.props;
        var layout = _.map(new Array(p.grid.items), function(item, i) {
            return {x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1, i: i};
        });
        return layout;
    },

    render: function() {
        var parentClassString = "desktop";

        if(this.state.zoomed){
          parentClassString += " zoomed";
        }

        return (
            var grid = this.props.grid; // this crashes the page

            <div className={parentClassString}>

                <ReactGridLayout className="gridLayout"
                    layout={this.state.layout} {...this.props.grid} > // this crashes the page
                    {this.generateGridDOM()}
                </ReactGridLayout>

            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = HomePage;
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm using webpack and it basically tells me that the page is not found

Comment: That's not very much to work with. Does that mean the packaging process doesn't even work? Otherwise I don't see what this has to do with webpack. What have you done so far to debug the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define that `var grid = this.props.grid;` within the `return`, put it before the `return`. The render method is just supposed to return a single root DOM node or React component.

If you look in the webpack build output it should point out the `var` is an unexpected token:

```
ERROR in ./file.js 
Module build failed: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (56:12)   
54 |   
55 |         return (
56 |             var grid = this.props.grid; // this crashes the page
   |             ^
```

Comment: I don't have that in my build output, so I guess it fails silently. Is there a flag I can set somewhere?

Comment: I tried setting devtool to #eval, but i don't see any build errors

Comment: how are you building webpack? you should at least see something similar in the chrome console, no?